# URL stays at root when using my domain, but with ip the URL changes to the paths of the links

Tags: url, links, godaddy, node-js

I am using GoDaddy to host my domain, but when I use my domain to go to my contact page (or any other page, including outside pages), it stays at `http://www.example.com`, instead of the correct url e.g. `example.com/contact`.

When I use my ip address and port `http://203.0.113.111:3050` it works correctly. But when I type `www.example.com/contacts`, it says `Cannot GET //contact`.

How can I fix this? Is it my nodejs server, or goDaddy?

Comment: If you are not using port 80 then you will need to specify this when using your domain name as well. In the first paragraph you state that "it stays at `http://www.example.com`", but in the second you say it reports "Cannot GET //contact"?

Comment: Your domain name seems to resolve to a different IP address than the one you are accessing your site through?

Comment: the site is www.mikeyhall.life
clicking on the contact link works, but going to www.mikeyhall.life/contacts gets the "Cannot GET //contact" error.
My Domain forwards to 104.154.170.86:3050

Comment: "My Domain forwards" - that would seem to be the problem. Everything is simply contained in an `iframe`. You need to correctly configure the DNS (`A` record or `NAMESERVER`s) to point the domain at your website hosting. (But why are you using port 3050?)

Comment: How would I do that? I use port 3050 because I'm already using port 80 for a php server. I'm also storing and serving my website off of a google cloud server. because I wanted complete control over my code.

Comment: Have you checked the docs... https://cloud.google.com/dns/quickstart / https://cloud.google.com/dns/update-name-servers / https://uk.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238 / http://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-to-change-godaddy-name-servers ?

Answer (score 1):

When you enter the domain name without port, it defaults to 80 for http or 443 for https. If you are using different port, like you are showing in your example (3050), you still need to use it even with domain name - domain.com:3050

DNS does not map anything to specific ports.

It looks like in your case the whole site is loaded in an iframe from the IP address when I open the domain name. It's not a very good or usual setup. You should run the webserver on port 80 and show the page directly, the you won't have problems with urls not changing, search indexing and usability.

Comment: The `iframe` would seem to be the result of GoDaddy's _domain forwarding_.

Comment: how can I get it out of the iframe? I already have a different server at port 80

Comment: What kind of server do you have on port 80? You can configure virtual hosts (apache) or server block (nginx) as reverse-proxy to direct the traffic coming to this domain to node server.

Comment: I have a php server at port 80, and a nodejs server at 3050, I can change that easily if I need to

Comment: You can use apache or nginx server on port 80 and make it pass incoming traffic for domain1.com to php and domain2.com to nodejs.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab#map-a-domain-to-a-service-running-on-your-vps-with-nginx